# Sending an already Gzip'd payload to the client

Tags: scala, playframework

I am struggling to send a response that is a Gzip file from S3. I am downloading the file from S3 as a `Array[Byte]` and then I would like to pass that along to the client and have the browser take care of the unzipping.

To be clear, I am not using the built-in gzipFilter in Play, because the data is already zipped.

I have this in my controller's action:

```
s3DAO.getFile(id).map(bytes => Ok(bytes).as("application/gzip”))
```

On the client (using Postman to debug), the `Content-Type` header is set to `application/gzip`, but the body comes out looking like this:

```
���[�W�$��j3��-��/�-HOz��ƒ@�HȄ%D���E�Л��%�=P�����$�*v7��X����������=޾x|��w������챕8�,��X���
```

I know that the bytes represent a valid payload, because if I insert code for decompressing it myself in the controller action, I can println it out fine:

```
val zipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes))
val rawString = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(zipInputStream, Charsets.UTF_8.name).mkString
println(rawString) // I can see my payload
```

I do not know what to do to debug this any further

Comment: Did you try to use an other http client like `curl` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted the same question on the [Play Gitter Channel](https://gitter.im/playframework/playframework) and found out the answer was to set the `Content-Type` to `octet-stream` and then to specify the encoding as gzip:

```
Ok(bytes).as("application/octet-stream").withHeaders("Content-Encoding" -> "gzip")
```